# swift - populating WKInterfaceTable

Tags: swift, watchkit, wkinterfacetable

following this tutorial... [here](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/A_watchOS_2_WatchKit_Table_Tutorial)

```
for (index, labelText) in stringData.enumerate() {
        let row = myTable.rowControllerAtIndex(index) 
        as! MyRowController
        row.myLabel.setText(labelText)
```

getting an error message that says:

> Value of type '[String]' has no member 'enumerate'

is there a Swift code update change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a really old tutorial, the function you're looking for is called `enumerated` now.

```
for (index, labelText) in stringData.enumerated() {
    ...
}
```